# perl regex - anchors and pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl

I coded perl regex to extract the words after a certain anchor, 
it seems like its not working. What am I doing wrong.

This is my actual output, I need to extract every number after groups keyword

```
$id cuser301 uid=2301(cuser301) gid=32(rpc) groups=32(rpc),1001(cgrp1),1002(cgrp2),1003(cgrp3),1004(cgrp4),1005(cgrp5),1006(cgrp6),1007(cgrp7),1008(cgrp8),1009(cgrp9),1010(cgrp10),1011(cgrp11),1012(cgrp12),1013(cgrp13),1014(cgrp14),1015(cgrp15),1016(cgrp16),1017(cgrp17),1018(cgrp18),1019(cgrp19),1020(cgrp20),1021(cgrp21),1022(cgrp22),1023(cgrp23),1024(cgrp24),1025(cgrp25),1026(cgrp26),1027(cgrp27),1028(cgrp28),1029(cgrp29),1030(cgrp30),1031(cgrp31),1032(cgrp32)
```

From the above, I run the id command and then would like to capture the numbers after groups Please help.

I am using the following.

```
my $check_groups = execute("\id $user"); #---> (execute is to run commands on the linux client, please ignore it)

my $new_groups = ('/^groups/',$check_groups); # ---> Now $new_groups should have all numbers after groups.
```

Comment: Please provide a sample output

Comment: Expected sample output should be : 32,1001,1002,1003... so on

Comment: This is amazing - https://regex101.com/r/uZ9tO6/1 Thank you very much

Comment: Accepted the answer, I can't upvote yet since I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $input = '$id cuser301 uid=2301(cuser301) gid=32(rpc) groups=32(rpc),1001(cgrp1),1002(cgrp2),1003(cgrp3),1004(cgrp4),1005(cgrp5),1006(cgrp6),1007(cgrp7),1008(cgrp8),1009(cgrp9),1010(cgrp10),1011(cgrp11),1012(cgrp12),1013(cgrp13),1014(cgrp14),1015(cgrp15),1016(cgrp16),1017(cgrp17),1018(cgrp18),1019(cgrp19),1020(cgrp20),1021(cgrp21),1022(cgrp22),1023(cgrp23),1024(cgrp24),1025(cgrp25),1026(cgrp26),1027(cgrp27),1028(cgrp28),1029(cgrp29),1030(cgrp30),1031(cgrp31),1032(cgrp32)';
print join ',', $input =~ /(?:.*groups=|\G.*?)\b([0-9]+)/g;
```

This is a common pattern; in more complicated cases where you want to ensure the `\G` branch only applies after the first non-zero-length match, you can use `\G(?!\A)` instead of just `\G`.

Comment: Great observation. Thank you ysth

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ echo <INPUT> | perl -ne 'print "$1," while /,(\d+)\(/g'
```

Check https://regex101.com/r/uZ9tO6/1

Comment: leaves out the 32, leaves on a trailing `,`